# SSH graphical session without graphical environment installed on server

Tags: 10.04, nautilus, ssh, debian

I am quite a noob in network/server stuff and I don't really know where to begin. I am using Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 on my PC, and I have also Debian SSH server on another machine in my LAN. I would like to be able to use a graphical session from Ubuntu while accessing Debian server. Is it possible, and how to do it?

I haven't installed any graphical environment on Debian SSH server, because it has no attatched monitor. When it had GNOME or XLDE installed it freezed while loading the system, with no monitor connected. So now it works only in text mode.

I can access it via ssh without any problem, but how do I make a graphical session?

**EDIT:** For example I would like to view and manage folders just like in nautilus.

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: In the graphic session, What all do you want?

Comment: Try `xrdp` . It doesen't run on `ssh` but uses the Remote Desktop Protocol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Only connecting to manage folders from Nautilus

To do this, you only need `ssh` installed on the server.

Go to File>Connect to Server

[image]

Fill the dialog up with the settings like so:

[image]

Make it a bookmark

[image]

Use the bookmark whenever required

[image]

---

### As far as SSH is concerned, AFAIK its not possible to `Xforward` a whole session

> Note: You need a graphical environment for this

What you want to use is probably `XRDP`

On the Debian install run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

And on ubuntu, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install remmina&&remmina
```

You'll get this window
[image]

Click New

[image]

Configure the settings

[image]

Click the connect button

[image]

You will get a session which has a gui of the server

Comment: @Misery I've edited it.

Comment: The nautilus solution is great!! Thanks a lot! That was something I was looking for:]

Comment: @AmithKK you forgot to mention that in order to have an RDP session you'd need a GUI installed on the server you're RDP-ing to.

Comment: From the question @ThomasWard , He already seem'd to have LXDE installed

Comment: @AmithKK then you didnt read.  "***I haven't installed any graphical environment on Debian SSH server, because it has no attatched monitor.*** When it ***had*** GNOME or XLDE installed it freezed while loading the system, with no monitor connected. So now it works only in text mode."